# Why cannot modern C++ IDEs auto-generate header files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, header-files

I understand the benefits and flexibility that header files provide, symbol discovery,  the speed-up of processing for the compiler, etc. What I don't understand is why modern C++ IDE's don't auto-generate header files based on the members/methods added into the code file, thus reducing the manual labour involved in keeping the header up-to-date with the code file, and vice-versa. Since the IDE only makes incremental changes to the header file, developers may modify the header and changes are preserved.

Refactoring could be provided for adding/renaming/removing method arguments, for renaming methods, for moving methods into another class, and so on. During such refactoring the IDE would take care of updating the header + source files.

The functionality could be similar to the Visual Form Designer in Visual Studio. When you design a form, the IDE auto-generates code for the same, which is stored in a separate, IDE-managed source file. Devs may also modify such code files, or may include additional code in the user-managed source file.

Working with professional C++ source code, I've encountered all kinds of dubious practices :

- Entire classes defined in the header file, that include function code *("why should I define a class in two places when I can define it in one?!")*
- Useful functions defined in the header file *("why bother keeping the header up-to-date, when I can define the function in the header itself?! let other devs use "go to declaration" to find the function if they don't think of looking in the header file!")*
- Missing header definitions for public/static functions *(reduces compilation time?, or saves dev. time?)*

Although I am not a professional C++ programmer, coming from a high-level background (JS, C#, AS3), I can feel the "downgrade" working with C++ first-hand and I don't see why some of these disadvantages cannot be eliminated by the IDE itself.

By no means am I mocking the IDE or the compiler in any way. I understand C++ allows for more complex methods of defining a program than modern-day languages do (eg. C#), and though the complexities of templating elude me, I'd like to see some of the benefits of higher level languages brought into C++ application development.

Comment: The basic observation of lacking tool support is valid. This is due to the complexity of the language. It appears to be changing due to the clang machinery. That said, the speculations here about why things are done in certain ways, are not valid. For example, much of the Boost library is header only libraries, for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question, I believe, is not correct.

The Eclipse Luna IDE can auto-generate implementation *stubs* (in a CPP file) after you define a function (or class member function) in a header file.

You type the following in the header:

```
class MyClass 
{
  void my_method(const OtherClass& o, const std::string& name) const;
};
```

Then click "Source > Implement Method".  Eclipse correctly generates something like this in a CPP file:

```
void MyClass::my_method(const OtherClass& o, const std::string& name) const
{
   // TODO: Auto-generated method stub.
}
```

I think this is a more typical use case than "[adding] members/methods... into the code file" and then "auto-generat[ing] header files".  The idea is that most developers will *design* (create) an interface, and then develop an implementation (sometimes in a CPP file).

As for "Useful functions defined in the header file", this is common practice where developers want their functions to be *inlined* by the compiler in many translation units.

Comment: Well, most people would want it the other way around: for example extracting a method from a function in the same source -> I would love an automatically generated entry for it in the header.